# Using value from select element in switch loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, select, switch-statement

I am trying to use values of options of dropdown menu in my loop, but i get uncaught error, all is undefined in filter1.

```
function filter1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("filter1").value;
    switch(x) {
        case all: 
        getElementsByClassName("1").style.display="none";
        break;
    } 
    console.log(x);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <select id="filter1" name="country" onchange="filter1()">
          <option value="all">All countries</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: `case "all"` Notice the quotes .

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Can I add this as an answer. I can mention you if you would like

Comment: @abhishekkannojia thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `quotes` to assign string in `case 'all'`.And add one option greater then only perform the change function

Change `document.getElementsByClassName("1")[0]` instead of `getElementsByClassName("1")` .Because the classname is the multiple selector

```js
function filter1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("filter1").value;
  switch (x) {
    case 'all':
     console.log('work')
      //document.getElementsByClassName("1")[0].style.display = "none";
      break;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<select id="filter1" name="country" onchange="filter1()">
          <option value="all">All countries</option>
          <option value="one">All one</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use This instead**

```
function filter1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("filter1").value;
    switch(x) {
        case "all": 
        getElementsByClassName("1").style.display="none";
        break;
    } 
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you forgot the quotes surrounding 'all'.

This should work:

```js
function filter1(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 'all': 
        //getElementsByClassName("1").style.display="none";
        console.log('all selected');
        break;
    } 
    console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select id="filter1" name="country" onchange="filter1(this.value)">
    <option value="all">All countries</option>
    <option value="us">US</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use the next construction:
`function filter1(){
return document.getElementById("filter1").getAttributes("value").then(function(){
})
}`